# Java Data structure to keep most bought books

Tags: java, data-structures, heap

Suppose a book site where most bought books needs to be recommended to users.
How can we most recent bought books recommendation?

My solution was using `PriorityQueue` as min-heap to keep most `k` entries, and if size increases, then `poll` one item.

Is there a built in java datastructure to do this? without requiring this pruning logic.

Comment: Most bought books and most recent bought books are different strategies.

Comment: TreeMap with key as book-id and value as Book object. Then you can implement a Comparator to sort by the number of books sold.

Comment: @Compass : it keeps most in the data structure, and in case of tie it prunes the older entry.

Comment: @HarshalParekh : `TreeMap` is also unbounded i believe.

Comment: LinkedHashMap has constructor parameter **access order**. If you create map with
 **access order = true**, if you perform get or put methods on map, entries will move into the end of map. You can store it like <ID,Book> and get last elements from it

Comment: I think the question could be explained better, you appear to have some grammar mistakes in your first (crucial) paragraph.  A [mcve] would also help, as the text description of your solution leaves a bit to be desired.